# Percentage not updating on stdout when running sdelete with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder

There is program named ["sdelete"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) that clearly delete disk free space, from sysinternals. If you execute with `sdelete.exe -c`, it will clear all your free space and it shows up the percentage about progress to stdout.

So I tried to make code using this:

```
public class deleteTest {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("sdelete.exe","-c");
        try {
            Process pGet = p.start();
            p.redirectError(p.redirectInput());
            InputStream is = pGet.getInputStream();

            int ch;

            while((ch = is.read()) != -1){
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

but it doesn't show up the percentage, it just keeps showing `Zeroing free space on C:\: 0%`. The process doesn't hang or freeze, but when it finishes all the percentage show up at once!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fear that you're going to complete miss the error stream and its messages with that set up. Consider changing

```
p.redirectError(p.redirectInput());
```

to:

```
p.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

This way, if your process building code is not correct, you'll at least see why.

Comment: Thanks but.. that's not reason this problem.. anyway i fix it. thanks

Comment: @user3329872: please let me know if you will now see error messages that weren't visible prior.

Comment: mm.. program does not make any error.. only problem is stdout percentage does not updated.. i think it seems like does not use stdout but make output to console..